# Signature SHA256WITHECDSA implementation not found

Tags: android, signing, spongycastle

I'm working on a project that creates a PKI to get a certificate request in Android.

Right now I'm using Spongycastle for it and It's working in Android 5 and up, but on 4.X it's showing me this:

```
Signature SHA256WITHECDSA implementation not found
 java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Signature SHA256WITHECDSA implementation not found
     at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:177)
     at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:170)
     at java.security.Signature.getSignatureInstance(Signature.java:178)
     at java.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:146)
     at org.spongycastle.jce.PKCS10CertificationRequest.<init>(PKCS10CertificationRequest.java:363)
     at org.spongycastle.jce.PKCS10CertificationRequest.<init>(PKCS10CertificationRequest.java:248)
     at com.unipagos.app.enrollmentprocess.EnrollmentStep5FragmentActivity.createPKI(EnrollmentStep5FragmentActivity.java:199)
     at com.unipagos.app.enrollmentprocess.EnrollmentStep5FragmentActivity.onPostCreate(EnrollmentStep5FragmentActivity.java:145)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1157)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2075)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code for creating the cert request is this:

```
public String createPKI(String mdnString) {
    try {

        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
        //KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "SC");

        ECGenParameterSpec ecGenSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("prime256v1");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(ecGenSpec, new SecureRandom());

        KeyPair kp =  keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

        publicKey = kp.getPublic();
        privateKey = kp.getPrivate();

        PKCS10CertificationRequest kpGen = new PKCS10CertificationRequest("SHA256WITHECDSA", new X509Name(String.format("UID=%s", mdnString)), publicKey, null, privateKey);

        String certRequest = Base64.encodeToString(kpGen.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        certRequest = certRequest.replace("\n", "");

        return certRequest;

    } catch(Exception e) {
        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.v("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The version of spongycastle I'm using is this:
sc-light-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar and
scprov-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar

¿Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the SpongyCastle provider ?

> static {
>       Security.addProvider(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());) 
>   }

Also, you will have to use this `KeyPairGenerator` instance:

> KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC",
>   "SC");

To be sure you are selecting SpongyCastle as the Security Provider.

Answer (score 0):

It's cause of the default bouncy castle provider added part of the Android OS. It can be solved using any one of the below mentioned approach.

### Approach 1

Replace the default OS level Bouncy castle provider with SpongyCastleProvider.

```
//Remove the existing bouncy castle provider initiated part of the Android OS using it's name.
Security.removeProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
//Add bouncy castle provider from library
Security.addProvider(org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
```

### Approach 2

And also there's one more option available. Get `KeyPairGenerator` instance by adding the provider instance part of the `getInstance()` menthod like below.

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
```

---

Same works with the Bouncy castle library as well. If you're targetting the app above Android 3.0(API Level 11), Suggest to use `BouncyCastle` library instead of `SpongyCastle` as [suggested by SpongyCastle library author](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle/issues/34) and follow any one of the approach mentioned above with the `org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider()`. Use the below dependencies in the app gradle to include the bouncy castle library.

```
// Bouncy castle
implementation "org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.68"
```

Refer below links to get the latest version of bouncy castle provider.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15to18